# OPPS - Class inheritance

Tags: c#, oop

I have a basic oops question

I have created an abstract class named xyz that contains common functionality for class Logger ,Queue,Encryption . The classes 
Logger ,Queue,Encryption derive from xyz. I need to further  create  classes ALogger ,AQueue & AEncryption. ALogger would contain
some functionality from Logger. It would be similar for AQueue  &  AEncryption.

So what is the best opps way of doing it ?

My solution is

```
Abstract class xyz 
{
}

Abstract class Logger : xyz 
{
}

Abstract class Queue: xyz 
{
}

Abstract class Encryption : xyz 
{
}

class ALogger : Logger 
{
}

class AQueue: Queue: 
{
}

class AEncryption: Encryption 
{
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have - do you have any specific problems or concerns?  If not this question is probably going to be closed as too vague.

Comment: I just want to ensure it is the best design

Comment: in future there could be more logger, Queue and Encryption classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this, honestly, is don't. None of these classes appear to have anything in common, so there's no reason for them to inherit from a common base class. Even if they did have something in common, that's not a good reason from a common base class.

In practice, inheritance usually isn't a good way for classes to share functionality. I won't say that's universally always true, but sooner or later the inheritance breaks down. One class needs to behave differently from the others, and so we end up going back and modifying a base class.

What is the functionality of `xyz` that all of these classes need to share? Put that in a separate class, and then have all of the other classes depend on that class. Just because they depend on the functionality in `xyz` that doesn't mean that they should inherit from it. The fact that three unrelated classes can require that functionality is enough to indicate that it belongs in its own class.